# a positive and negative checker with odd and even checker

Tags: java

How can I check if an input number is negative or positive, and if it is positive it will check again if it is odd or even, and if it's negative an error message will appear and ask again the user if he/she wants to check another number?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddEvenChecker{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int integer=0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            if (integer>=0) {
                System.out.print("Enter a positive Integer: ");//gets the user input
                integer = sc.nextInt();
            }

            if (integer<0) { // checks if the entered number is a positive integer
                System.out.println("Error");
                System.out.print("Do you Want to Continue?  y for Yes, n for No: ");
                String choices = sc.nextLine();

            } else if(integer>0) {
                if (integer%2==0) {
                    System.out.println("Even");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Odd");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with provided code?

Comment: You could change `if(integer>=0){` to `while (integer <= 0) {` This will loop until user enters a positive number.

Comment: the question "do you want to continue prints 2 times and i cant condition the input"

Comment: i cant end the statement if the user enters n which is no

Comment: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: the above code will go in infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
choices = sc.nextLine();
if(choices.equals("n") || choices.equals("no"){
 return;
}
else if(choices.equals("y") || choices.equals("yes"){
 break;
} else {
System.out.println("invalid key"); 
 }
} while(!choices.equals("n") || (!choices.equals("no") || (!choices.equals("y") || (!choices.equals("yes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OddEvenChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int integer = 0;
        String flag = "y";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner intScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive Integer: ");//gets the user input
            integer = intScanner.nextInt();

            if(integer>0) {
                if(integer%2==0) {
                    System.out.println("Even");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Odd");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("This is negative number. Try again.");
            }

            System.out.print("Do you want to Continue?  y for Yes, n for No: ");
            flag = sc.nextLine();
        } while(!(flag.equals("n") || flag.equals("no")));
    }
}
```

What do you think about this approach? Does it meet requirements?

Comment: yes but the question do you want to continue will only prompt if the user enters a negative number but i already fix it thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here
```

public class OddEvenChecker{

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int integer=0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        if (integer>=0) {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive Integer: ");
            integer = sc.nextInt();
            if(integer%2==0) {
                System.out.println("Even");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Odd");
            }
        }

        if (integer<0) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.out.print("Do you Want to Continue?  y for Yes, n for No: ");
            String choices = sc.nextLine();

        }   

   }


    }
```

}//Maybe this is the best and easiest way to do this.

Comment: the "even" or "odd" should not be outputted if a the user inputs a negative number

Comment: Well it won't. Run it if u want.